# SQLite SAVEPOINTS: how does ROLLBACK works in conjunction with RELEASE?

Tags: sqlite, release, rollback

I probably misundertood something about SAVEPOINTS in SQLite.

I am using C API in an application, where we run a bunch of inserts, and in case something fails, we should give up on all the inserts alltogether.

I am aware I could BEGIN TRANSACTION for such a simple scenario, but I fear that the scenario could get a more complicated, and nesting might become a requirement, that's why I went for SAVEPOINTS.

Anyway, here is an extract of SQL statements I run:

```
SQL> SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT_20170524_172706;
SQL> INSERT, SELECT STATEMENT (no COMMIT or END TRANSACTION)
SQL> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT_20170524_172706;
SQL> RELEASE SAVEPOINT_20170524_172706;
```

Basically I create a new savepoint based on the timestamp, before I start inserting and selecting data from the database.
Then one operation fails and I need to bail out, so I rollback to the savepoint I just created.
In the end I want to get rid of the savepoint I wont need anymore, since I dont want to clutter the database with useless savepoints, hence I ran RELEASE . In this case I find myself with the database filled with all the data inserted by statements that were supposed to be rolled back.

If I dont execute the RELEASE statement, then the database looks just fine, but I wonder what happens with the abandoned SAVEPOINT which will never be referenced anymore.

Which wrong assumption am I making? What happens to SAVEPOINTS if I dont release them, are they going to be 'dropped' as I close the 'connection' to the DB file?

Comment: Works for me. Provide a [mcve]. See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html).

Comment: @CL what exactly does work for you? Here I am not implying that it does not work, but rather that I am doing something wrong and that unfortunately I cannot figure out what it is. In fact, if I read the documentation (which is something I did repeatedly), I see no reason why I should find records inserted after I created the savepoint, to which I have rolled back to.

Comment: When I execute those four commands, the effects of the second command are properly rolled back.

Comment: By the way, I figured out the reason: I had `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF`, which unfortunately is not mentioned in the SAVEPOINT documentation page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF`